# Fetch as Google - Temporarily Unreachable ONLY on Mobile

Tags: dns, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot, google-crawlers

I have created a new website www.bucketshowers.com and I tried to index it using google webmaster tools. Fetch as Google for the desktop worked just fine, but doing the same for mobile shows an error "Temporarily unreachbale". It's been a few days and the website REALLY is not avaible on mobile. It's driving me nuts. Here're is some information and things I have already tried:

- Website is made with WP
- I have disabled all SEO/meta tags plugins and I added a very basic robots.txt http://bucketshowers.com/robots.txt
- I tried waiting 15min between fetching the root page on mobile
- I have checked source code for the homepage to make sure there are no meta tags with nofollow or noindex attributes

I baffled by this issue and I would gladly take any advise/pointers what else can be done. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There is 5 reason why you are getting this error in your webmaster Server response time, CND, Unwanted Plugin, Site Loading Speed and much much more please check the below link to get a clear idea. with a detail explanation. https://www.blazingcoders.com/google-webmaster-temporarily-unreachable

Answer (score 0):

The crazy thing was, that it was caused by WP Statistics plugin, which is probably the most popular from its kind - 500k downloads. When I deactivated it, everything is fine, google fetches of the mobile and the website is available. Incredible! I'm still searching for the actual problem within that plugin.